# How do I duplicate / copy an Outlook MailItem

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I have a user who sends `eMails` to a large "To" list, Sometimes over 20 addresses.  With this large a `"To"` list, the received mail sometimes ends up on the recipient's SPAM folder.  Obviously, we'd like to avoid  this.

My idea is to have the user create an original `eMail` and then run a Macro.  The Macro would loop through all the `eMail` addresses in an Excel worksheet and then copy the original message and send it to each recipient individually.

I'm unsure as to how to copy a `MailItem` from the original to a new `MailItem`. The Excel looping works fine.

Here's my abbreviated macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Send_emails()
'.
'.
Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
Set objWrdApp = objDoc.Application
Set objSelection = objWrdApp.Selection
'Loop through the Rows in the worksheet.  Start at row 2 to ignore header
For lngCurrSheetRow = 2 To lngLastSheetRow
    strEmailAddress = objWorksheet.Cells(lngCurrSheetRow, 1).Value
    'Set objNewMail so that the new message is created and can be referenced.
    Set objNewMail = Application.CreateItem(0)
    With objNewMail
        .Body = objSelection
        .To = strEmailAddress
    End With
Next lngCurrSheetRow
'.
'.
End Sub
```

Comment: You can specify all the reveivers as bcc

Comment: Hi Mr. Zach.  multiple addresses in the bcc field seems to be caught by the spam filters as well.

Comment: Then you have problems some where Else. Look into how to prevent emails going into spam. Using spf records, dmarc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To copy mailitem.body Example would be*

```
Option Explicit
Sub Send_emails()

        Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

        Dim objNewMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set objNewMail = Application.CreateItem(0)

        With objNewMail
            .Body = olMsg.Body
            .Display
        End With
End Sub
```

For HTML Body simply do **`HTMLBody = olMsg.HTMLBody`**

Comment: Hi 0m3r.  Thanks.  That worked.  I had to change the SET olMsg to:SET olMsg = objInspector.CurrentItem  That worked fine.  However this doesn't copy rich text attributes (Bolded text, Different font size, etc.).  I'm expecting to use WordMail as the editor.  I have a statement to check for that earlier on in the macro (If objInspector.IsWordMail <> True Then.....)  Thanks for answering this Copy question, but how can I get it to copy RICH TEXT?  I should have specified that originally.

Comment: Update:  I used RTFBody instead of Body (.RTFBody = olMsg.RTFBody).  That's better.  It preserves the Bold, Underscore and Hyperlinks nicely.  But it doesn't handle a font size change (say from 11 to font size 24) or to include different font families (Arial, Times New Roman, etc.).

Comment: Hi user3138025.  HTMLBody on both sides of the equation works perfectly.  That statement within the With / End With series now reads: .HTMLBody = olMsg.HTMLBody   Many thanks for your help.